# PHP - Write from to drive after reading from file_get_contents

Tags: php

I currently read in files that are uploaded with file_get_contents but now I would like to write these files to the server drive. These are all different image types so I cant just use imagepng or could I?

Below is the code I use to get the file information when uploaded and then the file name I would like to store.  I understand I could use move_uploaded_file to move the uploaded file but I am doing other stuff with the file so would like a different function to write the file to the server.

```
// LETS GET THE UPLOADED FILE DATA
$upload_file            = basename($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']);
$file_parts             = explode('.', $upload_file);
$file_extension     = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
$file_mimetype      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type'];
$file_content           = file_get_contents($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
$file_size              = filesize($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);

// WHAT IS THE FILE NAME WE WOULD LIKE TO USE
$file_name = md5($upload_file . '' . time()) . '.' . strtolower($file_extension);
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the built-in function [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: I agree with Ed. It is not necessary for you to write your own function or even a wrapper function for what you want. You can manipulate the file by storing $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'] to a variable `$file_i_want_manipulated = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']` ... do whatever you want with the file and then use move_uploaded_file() to store the result.

Comment: Problem is that I am storing / changing files in the Google Cloud Storage which through an API which I have the files contents in a variable so I want to be able to resize the images stored inside our bucket so to do so I am trying to write out the string to a file... then resize the image... then read the image contents and store back inside the bucket. So the function I am trying to develop would help in files that are uploaded along with files that have already been uploaded that I am trying to alter.